# Create a brick containing a single coin?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In Super Mario Maker 2, when I add a coin to a standard (brown) brick block, that block ends up containing multiple coins.

Is it possible to create a standard brick block that contains a single coin? If so, what's the procedure to do so?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution online that might help:
https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3ysxtv/want_brick_blocks_to_spawn_just_one_coin/

The procedure is to place down a coin next to your brick block.
Then give the coin wings (With your finger hold down the coin, then select the wings) and finally put that coin with wings inside the brick block.

I have tested this myself and it works.

Note: It seems at the moment impossible to put a coin inside a brick block without wings.

Comment: I tried, when that coin comes out from brick, it'll be a moving coin, not directly earned by player. Any more solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can preactivate the brick with a moving shell, if enough time elapses before the player hits the brick then only 1 coin can be obtained.

Outside of this I do not know* any other way for a single coin to be activated from a brick.

*Based on limited SMM2 experience.

Comment: Won’t the player obtain 2 coins? One when the shell hits it and one when they hit it. Also, this seems like it would be quite annoying to have to go through this just to place a single coin in a block.