# How can I create a one-way warp pipe?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In Super Mario Maker 1, it was possible to create a one-way warp pipe -- a warp pipe that can be traversed normally from one end, but where nothing happens when Mario attempts to enter it from the other end -- by placing two pipes over the top of one another in the editor. I used this technique frequently in SMM1 to, for example, create nicely-flowing "bonus rooms" where Mario would enter on one end and exit on the other.

Super Mario Maker 2 doesn't allow warp pipes to be placed over the top of one another in this manner.

Is there a way to create a one-way warp pipe in Super Mario Maker 2? If so, what is the procedure?

(Note: I'm aware that a workaround for this problem is to place the "out" end of the pipe in a location where Mario can't reach it, e.g. high above the ground, or horizontally-facing and not at ground level. I'm interested in a solution that creates an actual one-way pipe, without using this workaround.)

Comment: One method that comes to mind immediately is to utilize one-way gates to prevent the player from accessing a pipe after they have left it. It isn't quite invisible like the overlaying pipes method, but given that it seems that you cannot overlay elements in the same way that you could in this game, this might be the best solution to make sure a pipe is one-way.

Comment: @Unionhawk That's a good suggestion! To clarify what I'm really after, though, is to create levels that look and feel like original Super Mario Bros. 1 levels; those levels obviously did not need to resort to one-way gates or other such visually-obtrusive widgets. With all of the wild things that are possible in SMM2, it seems quite odd that it's (evidently?) not possible to do certain simple things that were common in SMB1 like create a one-way pipe, or create a brick block with a coin in it (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353648/create-a-brick-containing-a-single-coin).

Comment: I know in 3d world there's a 1 way warp block

Answer (score 1):

(Update 2)

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
         P   P
         P   P
         PPPPP
```

- P: pipe
- X: Wall

This pipe will allow player go back to previous stage, if player have fly ability,  or jump high enough.

---

(Update) Horizontal pipe solution:

```
W
A
LPPPPP
L    P ->
W    P 
APPPPP
L     ******
L
GROUND GROUND
```

- P: pipe

Make sure there is no platform in * area, so that player would not be able to go back through pipe.

Also, you need to prevent using any "able to be grabbed / portable object(Mario can stand on it)" from your course, or just simply put your pipe high enough.

---

(Original Vertical pipe solution) Put a **Bridge** over a pipe, for a vertical pipe.

Here's my concept :

```
H----H
HPPPPH
HP  PH
HP  PH
GROUND GROUND
```

- H: Hard block
- -: bridge
- P: pipe

It looks creepy, but seems no other solution for a vertical pipe.

Comment: The asker says that he is trying to avoid using "one-way gates or other such visually-obtrusive widgets". Do you think a bridge would be visually obtrusive?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will have to have some sort of structure at one end of the pipe, but you can choose to have it in the bonus room side rather than the overground side, to be less obtrusive, but this does mean you can enter the "exit pipe" on the overground, even if it kicks you back out again. This seems to be how Nintendo did it in their recreated retro levels in SMM/SMM3DS.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn’t in the original SMB1, but if you have any sort of slope after the pipe you’re coming out of, you can’t go back into the pipe. Just make sure that the sloped surface starts right when you come out. This looks pretty smooth in my opinion. I use it in quite a few of my levels.

Answer (score -3):

If you're in the 3d world theme you can use crates on the end that you enter. To go in you can just throw them, but when you try to go back through your path will be blocked.

Comment: While I agree this would be a good way of doing this, the OP specifically states they want to make recreate levels from SMB1, which would pretty much outlaw any theme that isnt the original SMB theme.